# Catching org_internal 403 error via Google's OAUTH?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, laravel-socialite

I have google OATH setup via socialite (only for within our organisation) and everything is working fine.

One thing I'd like to try and do is catch this "error" and get redirected back to our login page with a custom message telling the user that they do not belong to our organisation.

[image]

In principle this works fine, they can just hit the back button... but for fluidity and design, I'd like to catch this and redirect back to our home page.

Is this even possible? If so, how would you recommend I go about it?

```
public function show()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function redirectToProvider($driver)
    {
        if( ! $this->isProviderAllowed($driver) ) {
            return $this->sendFailedResponse("{$driver} is not currently supported");
        }

        try {
            return Socialite::driver($driver)->redirect();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
   
            return $this->sendFailedResponse($e->getMessage());
        }
    }


    public function handleProviderCallback( $driver )
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendFailedResponse($e->getMessage());
        }

        // check for email in returned user
        return empty( $user->email )
            ? redirect()->intended('/login?failed=1')
            : $this->loginOrCreateAccount($user, $driver);
    }

    protected function sendSuccessResponse()
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/');
    }

    protected function sendFailedResponse($msg = null)
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/login?failedResponse='.$msg);
    }

    protected function loginOrCreateAccount($providerUser, $driver)
    {
        // check for already has account
        $user = User::where('email', $providerUser->getEmail())->first();

        // if user 
        if( $user ) {
            // update the avatar and provider that might have changed
            $user->update([
                'avatar' => $providerUser->avatar,
                'provider' => $driver,
                'provider_id' => $providerUser->id,
                'access_token' => $providerUser->token
            ]);
        } else {
            return redirect()->intended('/login?noUser=1');
        }

        // login the user
        Auth::login($user, true);

        return $this->sendSuccessResponse();
    }

    private function isProviderAllowed($driver)
    {
        return in_array($driver, $this->providers) && config()->has("services.{$driver}");
    }
```

Comment: You cant there is no call back that is redirected to your app.

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, thanks for the response! So this is not possible to do, or am I missing something?

Comment: set a timer in your app and if it times out assume there has been an error

Comment: Where would you put this timer? As soon as the user clicks the link to sign in via google, it redirects to the oath page which I believe is out of my hands? I can only interact with it via callbacks

Comment: Like i said in my first comment there is no callback.  Your going to have to be creative.  Timer was a wild guess on my part i dont know how your system is designed.